# Facing this error in MASK RCNN "name 'COCO' is not defined"

Tags: python, ipython, faster-rcnn

I'm working on MASK RCNN repository and I ran demo.ipynb file but when I want to run the other notbook files from this repository such as "inspect_model.ipynb" or "inspect_data.ipynb" I face to this error in "Loading Dataset" part:
**

```
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
4 elif config.NAME == "coco":
5 dataset = coco.CocoDataset()
----> 6 dataset.load_coco(COCO_DIR, "train")
7
8 # Must call before using the dataset

/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/MASK RCNN/samples/coco/coco.py in load_coco(self, dataset_dir, subset, year, class_ids, class_map, return_coco, auto_download)
109 self.auto_download(dataset_dir, subset, year)
110
--> 111 coco = COCO("{}/annotations/instances_{}{}.json".format(dataset_dir, subset, year))
112 if subset == "minival" or subset == "valminusminival":
113 subset = "val"

NameError: name 'COCO' is not defined**
```

For information, I'm running this code on Google COLAB.
I would be appreciated for any help.